# Where is this fence boardwalk located in Victoria, BC?

Tags: canada, where-on-earth, identify-this, victoria-bc

The following screenshots are from [this video by Ms Vernice Patricia Tan](https://youtu.be/QOocpLZzLlg):

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is the [Ogden Point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogden_Point) breakwater.

[image]